# How to scan many RRD files fast

Tags: rrdtool

I need to compare two sets of RRD files (few millions) that should be the same, but possibly are not. How to scan them as fast as possible? Its enough for me to obtain information produced by

```
rrdtool info
```

command. Currently on my disks this operation takes a day.

UPDATE:
I develop in Python. Probably taking the first few structures of RRD binary file and generate MD5SUM for it could narrow the number of files I need to compare completely with rrdtool info. The problem is how to find how many bytes to read from the file to make the check valuable.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at rrd_format.h ... the interesting bits regarding the structure of the rrd files are all at the beginning of the file.

Using the python bindings for rrdtool info instead of calling the command (if you are not already doing that) should speed things up.

On the other hand, if you have two rrd files, created with the same parameters, but then updated with different values, could still have the same header. So just comparing the headers could be misleading unless you did not mention some additional info you have, like unique DS names or something like that.